Deployment Failed with error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages'" error?
I've been using AWS CodePipeline to execute a CI/CD pipeline. The 'build' stage performs correctly, which uses both the 'Dockerfile' and 'requirements.txt' files, whereas the 'deploy stage' utilizes Python files. Upon attempting, I encounter this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/MythicalMysfitsService/mythicalMysfitsService.py", line 3, in <module>
from urllib3.packages import six
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages'**

But the strange thing is that I already have 'urllib3' installed, based on modifying my Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES 1
# Update and install required packages
RUN echo Updating existing packages, installing and upgrading python and pip.
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install python3 -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
RUN pip3 install --upgrade flask
RUN pip3 install -U flask-cors
RUN echo Copying the Mythical Mysfits Flask service into a service directory.
# Copy application files
COPY ./service /MythicalMysfitsService
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /MythicalMysfitsService
RUN echo Installing Python packages listed in requirements.txt
# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install boto3
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 uninstall urllib3
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -U urllib3
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade urllib3
RUN echo Starting python and starting the Flask service...
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["mythicalMysfitsService.py"]


As well as my 'requirements.txt.' file:
boto3>=1.11.16
Werkzeug==2.3.0
Flask==2.3.0
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.
flask-cors==4.0.
requests
six
urllib3

I also have modified my 'mythicalMysFitsService.py' Python file to try importing urllib3:
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, Response, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from  urllib3.packages import six
from .packages.six import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection 
from .packages.six import HTTPException
import mysfitsTableClient

# A very basic API created using Flask that has two possible routes for requests.

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# The service basepath has a short response just to ensure that healthchecks
# sent to the service root will receive a healthy response.
@app.route("/")
def healthCheckResponse():
    return jsonify({"message" : "Nothing here, used for health check. Try /mysfits instead."})

# Returns the data for all of the Mysfits to be displayed on
# the website.  If no filter query string is provided, all mysfits are retrived
# and returned. If a querystring filter is provided, only those mysfits are queried.
@app.route("/mysfits")
def getMysfits():

    filterCategory = request.args.get('filter')
    if filterCategory:
        filterValue = request.args.get('value')
        queryParam = {
            'filter': filterCategory,
            'value': filterValue
        }
        # a filter query string was found, query only for those mysfits.
        serviceResponse = mysfitsTableClient.queryMysfits(queryParam)
    else:
        # no filter was found, retrieve all mysfits.
        serviceResponse = mysfitsTableClient.getAllMysfits()

    flaskResponse = Response(serviceResponse)
    flaskResponse.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

    return flaskResponse

# Run the service on the local server it has been deployed to,
# listening on port 8080.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)



You should really remove all the individual pip install commands and just use the requirements file. It'll be easier to upgrade in the future

And why pull an ubuntu image instead of python:3? You might be running into a Python version compatibility issue

You do make a good point regarding the pip install commands. The only reason why the ubuntu image was used was that its initial setup used the ubuntu image at the start, and building the docker image worked successfully using this approach. That, and the AWS CodeBuild has the docker version using an operating system: of Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (containerized) and the OS Type as Linux.

If using the requirements.txt file would be done instead, where would I apply the pip install commands?

You already have RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt, so I'm suggesting removing all the other individual pip install commands. I don't think Codebuild/CodePipeline is the issue here unless you cannot reproduce the error locally. Please show where you're trying to use the import in your file? from  urllib3.packages import six

Oh, I see what you mean. I'm inclined to agree that neither Codebuild/ CodePipeline are the problem, but rather the provided code itself. So I'm trying to import from  urllib3.packages import six from my mythicalMysfitsService.py file, which starts at the top with: import urllib3 from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, Response, request from flask_cors import CORS import mysfitsTableClient app = Flask(__name__) CORS(app)
I tried importing the urllib3 to see if it would resolve the error, but it still shows up.

six is never used outside of the import? What is this module needed for? How does it differ from some local module .packages.six?

Exactly! Those were my observations as well. My guess is that it may be tied to one of that urllib3 package that may have been associated with misaligned versions not being properly installed , or some dependency that likely generated some form of conflict. Thankfully, setting the ubuntu version to "20.04"  and removing the "ENV PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES 1" command seemed to resolve this issue for me.
